# Azure tools so unstable

Tags: azure

I'm having a hard time developing with Azure tools, it throws all kinds of errors about DF agent...

Also, I'm unable to debug since I configured multiple sites for one web role. It keeps saying something about a "syntax error" (the debug request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax). Then I restart the emulator and sometimes work, some times not.

I made my hosts file to point to 127.255.0.1, as I read in some blogs,  but that does not resolve my issue.

Another random error says something like "there is already an endpoint listening to dfservice..."

I spend 90% of my developing time struggling whit this issues...

Comment: Is there a question here? Ranting might be better done on a blog or Twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you are getting random error as "there is already an endpoint listening to dfservice...", I can point you out towards right direction.

The above problem is described in details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh472164.aspx) and it is due the to fact that some application is trying to access to same port which is used by DFAgent. Please follow the article to troubleshoot this issue.

As you also mentioned that restart Emulator does work for a while, it seems some other application and service is interfering with Emulator/DF configuration. Sometime, reducing the number of running process/services does help in such situation.

Comment: Thanks, but that article applies to SDK 1.5, I'm running 1.7 and Visual Studio 2012.

Anyway, none of those ports is in use.